# ADO, how to update edited recordsets only when I want?

Tags: sql-server, ado

I'm accessing SQL Server via ADO. 
I have a recordset and I'm modifying some fields. 
I want to update all the modifications only when I want.

In example, if I have an error, the program will end anormaly and the possible updates would be not done. Or I show a final messagebox to ask for confirming .

I'm using  "adOpenDynamic","adLockOptimistic".

I'm changing the info without using any recordset 'edit' previous command neither 'update'. Just `rs.fields("this")=newdata`;

I thought that all changes were temporary until I execute updatebatch. Are they???

Also I have not used rescordset.edit/recordset.update commands.
(directly I change the values of fields)

What is happening? What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Some parts of your question aren't comprehensible, like what you mean by 'expressly' and 'secuence'

Comment: I hope now it is clearer.

Comment: I'd need a "NOT_UPDATE_UNTIL_I_SAY" parameter / comand